# Firebreath mac os x create NSTextField in plugin window

Tags: macos, npapi, firebreath

I writing `NPAPI` plugin with `Firebreath` framework on Mac OSX.  
I need create NSTextField in plugin window. 
First, i try create `NSWindow` with `init` function

```
(NSWindow *)initWithWindowRef:(void *)carbonWindowRef
```

But WindowRef always null (i try get it after FB::CoreGraphicsDraw event)

```
void Plugin::onCoreGraphicsDraw(FB::CoreGraphicsDraw* evt, FB::PluginWindowMacCG* win)
{
    WindowRef win_ref = win->getWindowRef();
}
```

win_ref always equal null.

How i can create `NSTextField` another method?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is impossible. Modern OS X plugin drawing systems do not give you a window; you need to either draw into a `CGContext` you are given, or vend a `CALayer`, depending on which model you use.

There's no way to use native controls in an OS X NPAPI plugin. If you want native controls on OS X, you need to build a stand-alone application, not a browser plugin.